# How to make an array corresponding to the index of rows and columns?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array M[i,j], where i, j are the indexes of rows and columns. The values of each position(i, j) should be ^5+3 for all i even number, and 7−^2 for all i odd number.
How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: at the moment I only have an array (4,5). I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple version:

```py
import numpy as np

ni = 50
nj = 100
m = np.zeros((ni, nj))
j = np.arange(nj)

for i in range(ni):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        m[i, :] = i**5+3*j
    else:
        m[i, :] = 7*i-j**2
```

Comment: "name 'j' is not defined", I get this

Comment: @gerard Look at my edit, I forgot to define `j`